# Touch Down Event, Change the image button

Tags: java, android

I know there already are many similar questions and answers here, I've done searching some and I think I should ask this as a new question as I still can't find the right answer for me.

So, I write a simple card game, and I got 90% of my knowledge from the book `"Beginning Android Games 2nd edition"` by Mario Zechner, I wonder if some of you have read it. I follow the guide during writing my game, I even use the framework he provides in the book (Mr.Nom game). I've asked in his forum, but no response, the forum is not too active anyway.

The book provide framework where there are method to draw Pixmap, draw line, etc.. all directly from code, so I never touch the layout, I don't use XML either.

The book uses model similar to MVC (model view controller), separating the world and the game. The presentation and the manipulation layerd. It separates each UI according the game state: Ready, paused, running, gameOver.

Now I am stuck at some code as I want to change my button image. I provide 2 image (Unpressed and Pressed), at first in so called (RunningUI) part, I draw Unpressed image. and simply when user touch the button (touch down only) I want to change the image to pressed image. And return back to unpressed image again after the touch is released.

```
private void drawRunningUI() {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    g.drawPixmap(Assets.buttonUnpressed, 70, 200);
}
```

The updateRunning code is here:

```
private void updateRunning(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents, float deltaTime) {        
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    int len = touchEvents.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
            if (event.x < 64 && event.y < 64) {
                if (Settings.soundEnabled)
                    Assets.click.play(1);
                state = GameState.Paused;
                return;
            }
        }

        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {
            if (event.x >= 120 && event.x <= 180 && event.y >= 250 && event.y <= 380) {   

                Assets.click.play(1);
                g.drawPixmap(Assets.buttonPressed, 70, 200);  <-- nothing happened
            }
        }
    }

    world.update(deltaTime);
}
```

I modified "some here and there", but still I don't get the result I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't know this framework and can only surmise how the canvas drawing is made, I suspect `drawRunningUI()` is called immediately after `updateRunning()` and "overwrites" the previous draw with `Assets.buttonPressed` (depends on how invalidation / redraw is handled).

Anyway, you should only draw in one place, and it then gets a lot easier. In your event handling code you should update a UI state which you would then use to draw the UI. Something like this:

```
private void updateRunning(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents, float deltaTime) {        
    int len = touchEvents.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
        if(event.x < 64 && event.y < 64) {
            if(event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
                // ...
            }
        else if (event.x >= 120 && event.x <= 180 && event.y >= 250 && event.y <= 380) {
            switch(event.type) {
                case TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP:
                    uiState.updateButtonState(ButtonState.RELEASED);
                    break;
                case TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN:
                    Assets.click.play(1);
                    uiState.updateButtonState(ButtonState.PRESSED);
                    break;
                default:
                    // nothing to do
            }
        }
    }

    world.update(deltaTime);

    // I suppose an invalidation has happened / a redraw will happen next
}

private void drawRunningUI() {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    g.drawPixmap(uiState.getButtonState() == ButtonState.PRESSED ? Assets. buttonPressed : Assets.buttonUnpressed,70,200);
}
```

This won't be enough but should illustrate the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much desseim , your illustration is more than enough , it works like magic !,  brilliant.. hehehe, i am so glad.. reading your suggestion really opened up my whole mind. thanks again. :)

Comment: Oh, great :) Looking at where `updateRunning()` and `drawRunningUI()` are called should also help make definite sense out of this. Especially since this is typical drawing paradigm ; in Android framework it would be similarly implemented in `onTouchEvent()` and `onDraw()` for example.